# What is defined by the Euclidean Square Norm?

Tags: geometry

I was just wondering what the definition of this is. Is it:

$(x_{i}^{2}-y_{i}^{2})^{1/2}$ for $i=1...d$ for some d-dimensional vector?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$\lVert x-y\rVert_2=\sqrt{\sum_{i=1}^d(x_i-y_i)^2}$$

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**: [Pythagorean Theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pythagorean_theorem)...